# wamp server only running local

Tags: windows, apache, wampserver

Ive been searching around the internet and I cannot not find the answer to why wampserver is only running on localhost.  I have pressed Put Online and I still do not know why it is only running offline.  Not sure if it is my wampserver setup or my router blocking me, so any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

To access your server from the internet you need to do a number of things not specifically related to WAMPServer.

First you need to port forward your router, this allows un-solicited traffic on port 80 throught the NAT router firewall protection, into your network where normally for security reasons it is not allowed in. This opens the port and makes sure that all traffic on port 80 of yor router is directed to the PC running WAMPServer i.e. Apache. So you will need to make sure that the PC running Apache has a STATIC ip address and is not being allowctae an IP by the routers DHCP server.

[This site can be very helpful with learning how to do that](http://portforward.com)

Once that is done you may also need to configure your software firewall running on the PC that has Apache on it to allow traffic on port 80 into the PC. Although you may have allowed this already when you first ran Wampserver after it was installed.

When you use the WAMPManagers `Put Online` and `Put Offline` that changes the Apache config (httpd.conf) and should change

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require local
```

which tells apache to only allow connections from the PC running Apache

To

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require all granted
```

which tells Apache that it is allowed to action connections from any ip address in the world

Answer (score 0):

1) Check you firewall setting 80 port enable

2) Check anti virus Blocking

3) c:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\conf\httpd.conf

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from none
Allow from all
```